# Change the Node.js GET /POST requests to the Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, ajax

I'm a beginner in `JavaScript` and working to make the same request from some `Node.js` backend code to by using the `Ajax` based `GET/ POST` requests. I use `MySQL` database. I have gone through some tutorials and get some understanding. For example, an `Ajax POST` request could be something like,

```
    $.ajax({

            url: '/walletinfo',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: addressName,
                address: wallet.getAddress()
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
```

The `Node.js POST` requests that I have is provided,

```
// initiations of the code 
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express()

const con = mysql.createConnection({

    host: "localhost",
    user: "testuser",
    password: "testpassword",
    database : 'wallet1'
});

con.connect(function(err) {

  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});


app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// initiations of the code
app.post('/walletinfo', function (req, res) {

    var sql = "INSERT INTO wallet_info (name, address) VALUES ('" + req.body.name +"', '" + req.body.address + "')";

    con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

        res.json(result)
  });
})
```

So, its seems that the `req` object build-up the `SQL` query and the `con.query` tries to execute it. If the `INSERTION` is done as expected, we embedded the `res` with the `result`.

It seems I have to do something with the `data: {
                name: addressName,
                address: wallet.getAddress()
            }` part of the `$.ajax` request and make the `con.query` call over there.

I also have a `GET` request to change from `Node` to the `Ajax`,

```
app.get('/walletinfo', function (req, res) {

    con.query("SELECT * FROM wallet_info", function (err, result, fields) {

        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(result);
        res.json(result)
  });
})
```

How to do it properly?

Comment: What do you exactly mean change from Node to Ajax? Are you looking for how to request them using ajax?

Comment: Yes, updated the language and hope it will help. Btw, `English` is not my first language.

Comment: So do you want to request these endpoints (`/walletinfo`) with Ajax from a webpage?

Comment: Yes. These are the same, but, the app I work on have many different end-points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your webpage you need to request the endpoint you want like this:

```
// GET Request
$.ajax({
    url: "http://yourdomain.com/walletinfo",
    method: "GET"
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data) // Your wallet info from the server (MySQL Result)
});



// POST Request
$.ajax({
    url: "http://yourdomain.com/walletinfo",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        name: "<NAME>",
        address: "<address>"
    },
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data) // Your MySQL Result from the query insert
});
```

You can find more info about jQuery ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Could you please see my code and provided an answer based on that? I have `SQL` queries inside the requests. So, this generic answer doesn't help me much.

Comment: Why would you be querying MySQL on a webpage? That would be a big security risk. You should always keep database functionality on the server side.

Comment: This is a demo app. See, we are dropping the `Node`

Comment: You can't query MySQL in a browser you need to have the MySQL drivers to do so which are provided via Node MySQL module.

You will need to request a page on a server somewhere.

Comment: Is there some way to make this with the `Ajax GET and POST` requests and how to do that? I have get `MySQL` here in the code, 

`const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({

    host: "localhost",
    user: "testuser",
    password: "testpassword",
    database : 'wallet1'
});`

Comment: Ajax is used to make requests from a webpage to another webpage, you can't create routes using Ajax.